# Sqlite database syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "task_management";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "employee";
public static final String ID_FIELD = "_id";
public static final String NAME_FIELD = "name";
public static final String TIME_DATE = "time_date";

public static final String EMPLOYEE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE"
        + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + "(" + ID_FIELD + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + NAME_FIELD + "name," + TIME_DATE + "time_date,)";
```

What is the wrong in my database?

My log cat shows that

> "TABLEemployee": syntax error.

How to solve it?

Comment: maybe you should remove the last coma! ->>time_date,)";<<-

Answer (score 0):

Add a space between `...TABLE"` and `EMPLOYEE_TABLE`...

like:

```
EMPLOYEE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE " + EMPLOYEE_TABLE...
                                  ^
                              add space here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String EMPLOYEE_TABLE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + EMPLOYEE_TABLE 
        + "(" + ID_FIELD + "integer primary key autoincrement," 
        + NAME_FIELD + "string," + TIME_DATE + "datetime)" 
        + ");";
```

What about this ?

Comment: Remove the last comma as Greg said.

Comment: Add another space between idfield and integer... Etc... Etc

Answer (score 0):

Your employee table sql is not correct.  In addition to syntax errors (missing spaces, missing end semicolon) you need to define the data type for the TIME_DATE column.

BTW, I've actually gone to the trouble of executing this sql statement on a SQLite database and it works.

Try this:

```
    public static final String EMPLOYEE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE "
        + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + " (" + ID_FIELD + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + NAME_FIELD + " TEXT, " + TIME_DATE + " DATETIME);";
```

Comment: owo you are realy josss.@Michael Krause